# Using RavenDB Embedded on Asp.Net 5 (vNext)

Tags: ravendb, lucene.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The new Asp.Net edition features the kpm (k package manager). It seems to keep the dependencies packages on `C:\Users\<UserName>\.kpm\packages`.

[image: And RavenDB dependencies are there too.]

And then, this is how the `project.json` is defined. RavendDB Embedded referenced at the very end.

[image]

But then, the access to `Lucene.Net.dll` is being denied.

[image]

I had no problems with other dependencies so far, this is the only time an assembly reference had been denied from access.

Comment: Is RavenDB supported on `aspnetcore50` (CoreCLR)? Or just `aspnet50` (.NET 4.5.x)? If RavenDB doesn't specifically target `aspnetcore50` you'll need to put the dependency under the `aspnet50`-specific group of dependencies (and possibly entirely remove `aspnetcore50` because presumably your app won't work at all on that platform - *yet*).

Comment: Only `aspnet50` is referenced under `frameworks` on **project.json**, the core was entirelly removed as it conflicted with other packages used in the project (and RavenDB as well).

On line **89** of [AssemblyExtractor](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Database/Server/AssemblyExtractor.cs), it tries to delete the .dll. There's where it fails.

Comment: Ah OK that's good. I tried digging into RavenDB but I'm not sure why it's trying to delete a file, let alone why that's failing... do you perhaps know which file it is failing to delete? Maybe it's an assembly that's already loaded by .NET and thus it's locked and can't be deleted. In previous versions of ASP.NET the assemblies were I think always shadow-copied, but for now in ASP.NET 5 there is no shadow copying. See this bug: https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/219 . Of course, I'm not certain it's the same issue, but it might be...

Answer (score 1):

RavenDB is packaging some dlls internally, and it needs to save them to disk when it is loaded, that is why it is trying to delete that file (and then write to it again).
If you grant permission to that folder, it should all just work for you.

Comment: I tried, even with administrator rights. `Lucene.dll` is being locked by .NET, it might be what @Eilon said above.

Comment: You can control where it goes using Raven/AssembliesDirectory

Comment: Perhaps the configuration page ( http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/server/administration/configuration ) could be updated to reflect this? It would have saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: Could you please describe how to set this option? In the new vnext environment there is no web.config and I haven't been able to find how to modify the "Raven/AssembliesDirectory" option

Comment: @Bjorn You can set it using `DocumentStore.Configuration.AssembliesDirectory`. Just make sure to set it before calling `DocumentStore.Initialize`